Geodesics for a certain model of $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$: How to solve this integral $\int\frac{dx}{a+b\cos(x)}$ with $b> 0$, $a^2+b^2=1$?
How to express the integral
$$\int\frac{dx}{a+b\cos(x)}$$
assuming $b>0$ and $a^2+b^2=1$ in the best simplified way possible?
I tried a few online computing tools, however those that can solve it do not consider all different cases, for example if $a=0$, or $a^2<b^2$ or $b^2<a^2$ or $a^2=b^2=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$...
For example, Wolfram shows us

However, this expression can work only if $b^2-a^2>0$.
Solving this integral would be really helpfull, since it has to do with geodesic equations on a model for $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ that I'm working on.

A. When $a=0$, $$I=\frac{1}{b}\int \frac{1}{\cos x}=\frac{1}{b}\ln \left|\sec x+\tan x\right|  +C$$
B. When $a=\pm b$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{d x}{1\pm\cos x} \\
& =\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{1\overline +\cos x}{\sin ^2 x} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{a} \int\left(\csc ^2 x \overline +\cot x \csc x\right) d x \\
& =\frac{1}{a}(\pm\csc x-\cot x) +C
\end{aligned}
$$
C. When $a>b>0$,
let $t=\tan \frac{x}{2}  $, then
$$
\begin{aligned}\int \frac{d x}{a+b \cos x}&=\int \frac{1}{a+\frac{b\left(1-t^2\right)}{1+t^2}} \frac{2 \cdot d t}{1+t^2} \\
& =2 \int \frac{d t}{a+b+(a-b) t^2} \\
& =\frac{2}{a-b} \int \frac{d t}{t^2+\frac{a+b}{a-b}}
\\& =\frac{2}{(a-b) \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}}\right)+C \\
& =\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \tan ^{-1}\left[\frac{(a-b) \tan \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$
D. When $b>a  >0$,
$$
\begin{aligned} \\
I & =\frac{2}{b-a} \int \frac{d t}{t^2-\frac{a+b}{b-a}} \\&= -\frac{2}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}} \tanh ^{-1}\left[\frac{(b-a) \tan \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$
E. When $a<-b<0$,
$$\begin{aligned} I & =\frac{2}{a-b} \int \frac{d t}{t^2+\frac{-a-b}{b-a}} \\ & =\frac{2}{(a-b) \sqrt{\frac{-a-b}{b-a}}} \tan ^{-1} \frac{t}{\sqrt{\frac{-a-b}{b-a}}}+C \\ & =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \tan ^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{b-a} \tan \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{-a-b}}+C \end{aligned}$$
